# Can you say "the sole one" instead of "the only one"?

Tags: only

And why/why not? The complete sentence is "You are my sole one in the world", it feels absurd and wrong but I can't really tell.

Thanks in advance!

Off-topic, huh. Well, let's go over it:
The research: The question is far too specific to be featured in any grammar book I possess(I did check). I also googled it but, again, far too specific and it also returned a number of unrelated results. I asked some native speakers I know and some of them said it works, others said it sounds off but none could give a reason.
The Learner's forum: I'd assume that if native speakers have a hard time agreeing on it, the question is somewhat above "learning" levels. If merely asking about English qualifies as "learner's", then this forum would be largely irrelevant.

Comment: In principle you could use ***sole*** there (it's not that uncommon in the collocation [*the sole **reason***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+sole+reason%2Cthe+only+reason&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20sole%20reason%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20only%20reason%3B%2Cc0)). But with ***one*** it's [**very uncommon**.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+sole+one%2Cthe+only+one&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20sole%20one%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20only%20one%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 3):

It helps to understand that the [antiquated definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sole) of the adjective "sole" is "without a companion" (see also, "solitary").  While we don't specifically use that meaning anymore, the words it is naturally combined with reflect that antiquated definition.  Thus, you can say "sole proprietor" because a store's proprietor could have a business partner, but you do not say "sole one" because the pronoun "one" will never have the possibility of a partner.

Though I canont find a specific rule to support this claim, the adjective "only" is generally used to separate the target noun from a group or to identify an individual element of a group.

> You are the only person I know who would do that.
>
> You are the only one in the class with a red shirt.

While the word "sole," in support of the antiquated definition, is more often used to indicate *there is no group*.

> You are the sole proprietor of this store.
>
> You are the sole winner of the reward.

Comment: My initial thought on this question was *It's just a matter of established idiomatic usage,* but that seemed a bit weak considering ***sole*** works fine with nouns like ***reason, survivor***. I'm now totally convinced that your *do not say "sole one" because the pronoun "one" will never have the possibility of a partner* is key here.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use it in the way you suggested, though there are other cases where "only" and "sole" can be used interchangeably:

> You are the only person I care about.
>   You are the sole person I care about.
>
> He was the only survivor.
>   He was the sole survivor.

I can't really explain **why** it doesn't work in your example, but it doesn't. It doesn't sound idiomatic. I'm not sure if it's actually wrong from a grammatical perspective.